# Why does Software & Updates affects do-release-upgrade command in terminal?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I have a curious for me question referring to Update Manager and terminal command `do-release-upgrade` as a user I've noticed lots of people ask questions when they run:

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

and it returns:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature[198B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool[1,147kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,148 kB in 0s(0B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'utopic.tar.gz' against 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'utopic.tar.gz'
```

but when you run:

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

it returns:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

And if I go to Software & Updates --> Updates --> Notify me of a new Ubuntu version and set it to `For any new version`

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

will return:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature[198B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool[1,147kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,148 kB in 0s(0B/s)                                                 
authenticate 'utopic.tar.gz' against 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'utopic.tar.gz'
```

and so will:

```
do-release-upgrade -c
```

will return:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '14.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

And if I set it to `Never` both commands `do-release-upgrade -d` and `do-release-upgrade -c` will return:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

But in Software & Updates I set all other updates to `Never` notify me as I do `dist-upgrade` via terminal only and it works indeed it upgrades all available updates and security patches.

[image]

Why is then it doesn't work with `do-release-upgrade`? Shouldn't it do what I tell it to do despite what is set in Software & Updates? Or is it just designed this way?

**Edit**

A small edition to the question to clarify it a bit more, I don't want to receive graphical notifications about new available updates or releases or whatsoever, so in Software & Updates I set updates & notifications to `Never` because I'd like to do this via terminal and everything works except `do-release-upgrade`

Comment: They all trace down to the same package: [`python3-apt`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-apt), all using the Python APT libraries. Is it surprising that they share settings?

Comment: interesting but my question why is `dist-upgrade` and other updates work when in Software & Updates it is set to Never but `do-release-upgrade` doesn't work.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` has nothing to go with release upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `do-release-upgrade` command, the Update Manager, the Software Sources program and the Software Centre all share a few common libraries and  configuration files.

The particular aspect you are looking at (the next version of Ubuntu you wanted to be prompted for), is set in the file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`.

You can edit it, and set the value of the `Prompt` option. Quoting the comments:

```
Default prompting behavior, valid options:

 never  - Never check for a new release.
 normal - Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
          release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
          the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
          release.
 lts    - Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
          will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
          the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
          used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
          release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
          determine if a newer release is available.
```

Both the GUI and the command line derive these settings (since eventually, they all end up using the Python class `UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease.MetaReleaseCore`, in which:

```
 # some constants
 CONF = "/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades"
 CONF_METARELEASE = "/etc/update-manager/meta-release"
```

And

```py
if parser.has_option("DEFAULT", "Prompt"):
    type = parser.get("DEFAULT", "Prompt").lower()
    if (type == "never" or type == "no"):
        # nothing to do for this object
        # FIXME: what about no longer supported?
        self.downloaded.set()
        return
```

So, this is how it has been coded, without any option to override the configuration file.

Therefore, if you want to disable the GUI notification, but be able to use `do-release-upgrade`, you will have to edit the configuration file. This can be done easily enough (replacing `lts` with `normal`, if you prefer):

```
sed -i.bak 's/^Prompt=.*$/Prompt=lts/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
do-release-upgrade -c
sed -i.bak 's/^Prompt=.*$/Prompt=never/' /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Note that there seems to be a directory for extensible configuration  (`/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.d`), but it seems to be unused as of now.

Comment: yes thank you for helping! That's what I've been looking for, that explains enough.

Answer (score 0):

This one is the best understandable explanation for me now e.g. when in Software & Updates --> Updates --> Notify me of a new Ubuntu version and set it to `for long-term support versions` then the output of `do-release-upgrade -d` will >= true, as `do-release-upgrade -d` stands for:

```
Check if upgrading to the latest devel (*development) release is possible
```

That would be >= (greater) release that you're currently running but not LTS release rather the one that is being developed (unstable).

But `do-release-upgrade -c` will >= false as it stands for:

```
Check only if a new distribution release is available
and report the result via the exit code
```

And that would be the LTS release (stable). And it will work only if there's greater LTS release available than you're currently running.

But if you set in Software & Updates --> Updates --> Notify me of a new Ubuntu version `for any versions` and that would mean for stable and unstable (devel) releases. Then both commands `do-release-upgrade -d` and `do-release-upgrade -c` or `-c -d` together will return positive. In this case `-c` can even be dropped as `-d` would make it work for both if any.

And in a case if notifications set to `Never` both commands will return negative. That could even be called a blocking feature as if you won't be able to upgrade release to any new version using either `-c` or `-d` in `do-release-upgrade` command. I except this as it was designed this way probably.

**P.S.**

**@muru**'s answer works for me even better than mine. Thanks :). But I'm also going to leave this one in a matter of iterest.

Comment: Cannot get it better, maybe somebody else understands of what I'm curious about :) any answer is welcome.

Comment: You say your question is about `dist-upgrade`, yet your answer doesn't mention it at all. What is it about, exactly?

Comment: the question says it affects `do-release-upgrade` command not `dist-upgrade` when I set in Updates to notify me on new releases or updates **never** and when I run `dist-upgrade` it upgrades packages if any needed to but if I run `do-release-upgrade` it says `nothing is available` though it is if I set it back to `any versions`

Comment: And as I said before, `dist-upgrade` has nothing to do with release upgrades. So, again, what is your question about?

Comment: ok like I said in my question **edit** how can I upgrade to next release via terminal if option (for graphical notifications) in Software & Updates --> Updates --> Notify me of a new Ubuntu version is set to `Never`?

Comment: So, you want to set that option using the command line, is that it?

Comment: I want the command `do-release-upgrade -c` or `do-release-upgrade -d` work as I tell it to in terminal I don't need a graphical notification about new release available that's what question is about because it doesn't work in terminal when Software & Updates --> Updates --> Notify me of a new Ubuntu version is set to `Never` that's why I asked is that designed so or it can be changed/achived somehow.

Comment: Also, for example if I set to notify me about new Ubuntu release to `any versions` I will be notified with every Ubuntu release (graphically, via update manager etc.) but I don't want to, I want to check in terminal for the new versions myself if I ever even want to but it won't be possible if I set to notify me about new Ubuntu release to `never`.